# How to get my app to be launchable via Google Now voice commands?

Tags: android, voice

My app's label is "Home+" but Google Now doesnt seem to recognize it when I say "open Home Plus", however the Google+ app does open fine when saying "open Google Plus". I changed the label to "Test app" and my application launched fine through Google Now so I know I have my intent filters set up properly.

Does anyone know any tips or tricks that might let my app labeled "Home+" launch via voice in Google Now the same way the Google+ app does?

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution?

Comment: I think it works to say "ok google + your app name". This only works when you have no weird names so google knows how to "write" your app by listening to your voice.